# flow types, casting to array type doesn't work from explicit type, but does from implicit type

Tags: javascript, flowtype, subtyping

Considering  the following lines

```
const a: Array<number> = [1,2,3];
const b = [1,2,3];
const q: Array<boolean | number> = a;
const r: Array<boolean | number> = b;
```

The above code works for lines 2 & 4 (`b` and `r`), however flow chokes on line 3, with the error:

> Cannot assign `a` to `q` because number [1] is incompatible with boolean [2] in array element.

This makes little sense to me, especially since the line below does work. Why does this not work, and how can I make it work?

---

As for an application of above: in my real working code I have a function that accepts any "simple javascript object" (an object without functions). Which I described by:

```
type primitive = boolean | number | string | void;

type plain_js_object = {
  [string]: (primitive | Array<primitive> | plain_js_object)
}
function theFunction(input: plain_js_object) {
    //do_things
    return JSON.stringify(input);
}
```

And then I have some other function that returns an array of integers, the function is then called like:

```
const fib = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5];
theFunction({sequence: fib});
```

Obviously `{sequence: fib}` is a of type `{sequence: Array<number>}` which is obviously a subtype of the plain javascript objects.

Comment: Don't know the actual answer, but if you were allowed to do `const q: Array<boolean | number> = a;`, then you could do `q.push(true)`, but that violates the type of `a`.

Comment: Creating a copy of the array seems to "fix" this: `const q: Array<boolean | number> = [...a];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some helpful info can be found about [`$ReadOnlyArray`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-readonlyarray). The issue (I think) is that `Array` is invariant, meaning `Array<number>` is not a subtype of `Array<number | boolean>`. This works fine:

```
const a: Array<number> = [1,2,3];
const b = [1,2,3];
const q: $ReadOnlyArray<boolean | number> = a;
const r: Array<boolean | number> = b;
```

My best guess is that Flow does something smart when the type is inferred from an array literal rather than explicitly typed.

As for your example, I didn't get any flow errors running 0.93, can you show a repro in a Flow Try link or something?

Comment: Well the "bug" in my applicaiton was due to a bit more complexity, and I fixed that too by encapsulating it with `$ReadOnly<>` (So not only the internal array are readonly, the whole object is/needs to be).

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it. If you found my answer helpful at all, please vote for it as well. :-)